# Blaze dynamic data binding

Tags: angularjs, meteor, pug, meteor-blaze

Following is the angular example for simple input field model binding.

```
<div ng-app>
  <div>
    <input type="text" ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here">
    <h1>Hello {{yourName}}!</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

How can I replicate the same functionality using meteor-blaze with Jade, i.e. input field change event will update the corresponding helper.

> Update

Below is my code in Blaze and Jade:

```
.form-group
 lable 
 | Click buttons to increase their values:
 input#user(type="text")
 span 
 |{{usernameinput}}
```

Below is javascript code:

```
Template.unitconversion.helpers({
    'nm': function(){ return "100" }
});

Template.unitconversion.events({  
    'keyup #user': function(evt, tmpl){
        var tor = tmpl.find('#user').value;
        console.log(tor);       
        //console.log(evt);
        //console.log(tmpl);

        Template.unitconversion.helpers({           
            'usernameinput': function()
            {               
                return tor
            }
        });
    }
});
```

I was expecting the helper function to update the 'usernameinput' whenever user input is changed but nothing happens. I do get the expected console output whenever input field changes.

Any help would be appreciated to solve it.

Comment: To answer this question, someone would have to speak angular, blaze, and jade. Can you more explicitly say what functionality is being replicated?

Comment: @DavidWeldon lol exactly, ravi: why don't you give it a try with Blaze or Jade and ask if you have an error or show us some code.

Comment: Why did you nest your helper inside of your event handler? It should normally be its own block. Furthermore you need to make `tor` either a reactive variable or a Session variable so that your helper will be reactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me answer your question in "spacebars". I think you should be able to translate it to "jade" easily. First make sure you add `reactive-dict` package:

```
meteor add reactive-dict
```

It's little more complicated than you might have expected, but the following code should do the the job pretty well:

```
<template name="hello">
  <h1>Wellcome {{myName}}!</h1>
  <p>
    Tell your name <input type="text" name="myName" value="{{myName}}"/>
  </p>
</template>
```

and the corresponding `javascript`:

```
Template.hello.onCreated(function () {
  this.state = new ReactiveDict();
});

Template.hello.helpers({
  myName: function () {
    return Template.instance().state.get('myName');
  },
});

Template.hello.events({
  'keyup input[name]': function(e, t) {
    t.state.set($(e.target).attr('name'), $(e.target).val());
  }
});
```

The reason this is so "complicated" is because Meteor does not offer a built-in two-way-data binding support. It does not mean it can't be done as the above example shows.

You can read more about two-way-data-binding in meteor cookbook here:

https://github.com/awatson1978/meteor-cookbook/blob/master/cookbook/data-binding.md#two-way-data-binding-1

Answer (score 0):

As per Michel Floyd guidance following is the working code:

Jade Template:

```
.form-group    
   lable 
     | Click buttons to increase their values:
   input#user(type="text")
   span
     | {{usernameinput}}
```

Javascript:

```
var usernameinput = new ReactiveVar(0);

Template.unitconversion.helpers({
    usernameinput: function(){ return usernameinput.get();
    }
});

Template.unitconversion.events({  
    'keyup #user': function(evt, tmpl){
        var tor = tmpl.find('#user').value;
        console.log(tor);
        usernameinput.set(tor);
    }
});
```